# sd card unrecognised after formatting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, formatting, sd-card

I have tried to insert an sd card in my computer but it doesn't recognize it, it is ubuntu which can't,windows does recognize it, I finally bought a new sd card,ubuntu could recognize it,but when I formatted it using gparted it wasn't there anymore.
I am in need of it in order to load a linux kernel and other related files.the teacher told me to buy a much "strong" sd card of a good brand which can be still be readable after formatting.
Do you have any idea on what the source of my problem is? or what brand of sd card I must get?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the sd card is visible from your windows pc, just use windows to load your linux iso. Please follow the instructions here https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/

I believe it will be of help